# Sign SAML messages - LightSAML SPBundle Configuration

Tags: saml-2.0, symfony4

In the bundle - what configuration or service override do I have to perform for the library to sign SAML messages before sending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IdP configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor
  xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
  xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
  entityID="some.provider.id">
  <md:IDPSSODescriptor
      protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
      WantAuthnRequestsSigned="true">
```

The last line is relevant.